# Special character breaking JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, special-characters

I am making a JavaScript flash card game for a mechanics website. Because I want to put equations on the cards I need to use a delta(Δ) sign.

A card might have: "The equation for power" on one side and "P=W/Δt" on the other. If the card starts on side one it will flip when the space key is pressed or when the flip button is pushed. However, if it starts on side two, the one with the Δ sign, it will not flip when the 'flip' button or space key is pushed.

I have tried different ways of writing Δ:

```
&Delta; &#x0394; &#916;
```

none of these worked.
My code is:

```js
//Copyright Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International 2017 Hazel Meehan


//array containing all options
var options = [ //counts from 0
  "Joules(J)", "Measure of Work",
  "Watts(W)", "Measure of Power",
  "Ek", "Kinetic Energy",
  "Ep", "Potential Energy",
  "Newtons(N)", "Measure of Force",
  "Pascals(Pa)", "Pressure",
  "ms-1", "Metres per Second",
  "ms-2", "Metres per Second Gained",
  "10N", "Value of Gravity",
  "Weight is a", "Force beginning with W",
  "The capacity to do work", "Energy is",
  "d = &Delta;v&Delta;t is the equation for", "The equation for distance",
  "W=F&Delta;d is the equation for", "The equation for work",
  "P=W/&Delta;t is the equation for", "The equation for power"
];

//initialize variables
var randomNum = 0;
var sideOne = " ";
var sideTwo = " ";

//choose new card using random number
var newCard = function() { //runs on 'next'
  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length);
  sideOne = options[randomNum];
  if (randomNum % 2 == 0) { //is the number even
    sideTwo = options[randomNum + 1];
  } else {
    sideTwo = options[randomNum - 1];
  }
  document.getElementById("card").innerHTML = sideOne;
};

//show other side of card
var flip = function() { //runs on 'flip'
  if (document.getElementById("card").innerHTML == sideOne) {
    document.getElementById("card").innerHTML = sideTwo;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("card").innerHTML = sideOne;
  }
};

//change card on key down
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.keyCode == '39') { //right arow key
    newCard();
  } else if (e.keyCode == '32') { //space bar
    flip();
  }
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h2>Flashcards</h2>
  <center><button id="flashButton" onclick="newCard()">Next</button></center>
  <br>
  <center><button id="card"></button></center>
  <br>
  <center><button id="flashButton" onclick="flip()">Flip</button></center>
</article>
```

Comment: It's working here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com) , you should probably add a `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag to your html in order to see them.

Comment: Works for me. What browser are you using? Anything logged in console?

Comment: I can reproduce the bug, it vanishes when i replace `&Delta;` with `Δ`.

Comment: @MrGeek It's not working for me, I tried adding <meta charset="uft-8"> and that didn't work. I tried running it in IE and it still isn't working.

Comment: @ASDFGerte that worked, thanks

Comment: Maybe, but it doesn't explain the described behavior. I'd prefer to know why it doesn't with your way, i assume something odd with it being interpreted and `innerHtml` but i don't know.

Comment: @ASDFGerte It might have something to do with the setting on my browser but I can't think what it might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When checking the element's `innerHtml` (`if (document.getElementById("card").innerHTML == sideOne)`), the string previously set has been interpreted as html and when retrieving it, the `&Delta;` will now be `Δ`. The comparison is then false:

`"d = &Delta;v&Delta;t is the equation for" !== "d = ΔvΔt is the equation for"`

Therefore it sets the `innerHtml` to the same side again.